# @Url.Action returns a null value within the jQuery .load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC so please keep the explanations simple and specific.  I essentially am trying to open a modal dialog using jQuery and @Url.Action keeps returning a null value.  When I forego @Url.Action and hardcode the path, it works fine.  Here's the code below.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function popupMobileDialog() {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 700,
                height: 500,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'CURewards Mobile Apps',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("MobilePopup", "MobilePopup", new { area = "Innerge.Plugins.PSCU"})');
                    //$(this).load('MobilePopup/MobilePopup');
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }).dialog("open");
            }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[Export(typeof(IController))]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "MobilePopup")]
[ExportMetadata("Plugin", true)]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MobilePopupController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MobilePopup()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Yay!!!  This is the modal popup window I've been waiting for.</p>
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.  If you need any more information, please let me know.  Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the "area" parameter in your `@Url.Action()`?

Comment: @Url.Action() works only inside .cshtml only. If your above code is in external .js file, declare global javascript variable in view and access it in external .js file.

Comment: @malkam - @Url.Action() is inside of a .cshtml file...the entire script is.  I just loaded the jQuery from the file.

Comment: Just check Url.Action value by alert(@Url.Action("MobilePopup", "MobilePopup", new { area = "Innerge.Plugins.PSCU"}))

Comment: @krillgar - I don't remember this exactly as a coworker suggested it while helping me yesterday, but I know the area parameter had something to do with some object not being in a class somewhere else in the code....that's all I remember, but it didn't work before he suggested it, so I should probably remove it.

Comment: @malkam If that code is within the View (cshtml file), and it appears as it is since it is within `<script>` tags, then the Razor engine will parse it as expected. It's only if you were to try to do that within a .js file that it won't work. You can definitely use the Razor engine inside on-page javascript.

Comment: @malkam - I did the alert() to check the Url.Action value and it was null.

Comment: Means something wrong with that Url.Action.Do you have Areas in your application?

Comment: Yes, there is an Areas.  I assume you're referring to a folder within the project structure?

Comment: As you're saying hardcode  path 'MobilePopup/MobilePopup' working fine, try with just '@Url.Action("MobilePopup", "MobilePopup")'

Comment: @malkam - Tried it and it still doesn't work.  My popup dialog was empty and when I did a view source, the load looked like this --> $(this).load(''); <--.  This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code resolved my issue.

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("MobilePopup", "MobilePopup", new { area = ""})');
```

My layout.cshtml file is located in /Views/Shared while MobilePopupController is located off of the root structure (/Controllers), in another area.  So, by adding the "new { area = ""}" parameter, it tells ASP.NET that it'll find the controller in the root/default area of the project, which is the project structure outside of any areas folder.  Without the area parameter, it tells ASP.NET to look in the current area for the controller.